# Convert multiple recursive calls into tail-recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, tail-recursion

Just wondering if a function like this can be done tail-recursively. I find it quite difficult because it calls itself twice.

Here is my non-tail-recursive implementation in javascript. (Yes I know most javascript engine doesn't support TCO, but this is just for theory.) The goal is to find all sublists of a certain length(size) of a given array(arr). Ex: getSublistsWithFixedSize([1,2,3] ,2) returns [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]

```
function getSublistsWithFixedSize(arr, size) {
    if(size === 0) {
        return [[]];
    }
    if(arr.length === 0 ) {
        return [];
    }
    let [head, ...tail] = arr;
    let sublists0 = getSublistsWithFixedSize(tail, size - 1);
    let sublists1 = getSublistsWithFixedSize(tail, size);
    let sublists2 = sublists0.map(x => {
        let y = x.slice();
        y.unshift(head);
        return y;
    });

    return  sublists1.concat(sublists2);
}
```

Comment: Any function can have at most one tail call. So no, unless you refactor it to use an explicit stack, you cannot do it with only tail recursion.

Comment: ^^^^^ IOW you *can* do it, if you refactor it to use explicit stack (i.e. keep track of what-to-do-next yourself, *not* rely on recursion to do it for you).

Comment: With more than one call the nature will be recursive and not iterative. You can use explicit stack or nesting continuations and while you have 100% tail recursion it is at a cost that probably is higher than just incrementing the stack size to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution with the help of an accumulator. It's far from perfect but it works.

```
function getSublistsWithFixedSizeTailRecRun(arr, size) {
    let acc= new Array(size + 1).fill([]);
    acc[0] = [[]];
    return getSublistsWithFixedSizeTailRec(arr, acc);
}


function getSublistsWithFixedSizeTailRec(arr, acc) {
    if(arr.length === 0 ) {
        return acc[acc.length -1];
    }
    let [head, ...tail] = arr;
    //add head to acc
    let accWithHead = acc.map(
        x => x.map(
            y => {
                let z = y.slice()
                z.push(head);
                return z;
            }
        )
    );
    accWithHead.pop();
    accWithHead.unshift([[]]);

    //zip accWithHead and acc
    acc = zipMerge(acc, accWithHead);

    return getSublistsWithFixedSizeTailRec(tail, acc);
}

function zipMerge(arr1, arr2) {
    let result = arr1.map(function(e, i) {
        return uniq(e.concat(arr2[i]));
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One such way is to use continuation-passing style. In this technique, an additional parameter is added to your function to specify how to *continue* the computation

Below we emphasize each tail call with `/**/`

```js
function identity(x) {
/**/return x;
}

function getSublistsWithFixedSize(arr, size, cont = identity) {
    if(size === 0) {
/**/   return cont([[]]);
    }
    if(arr.length === 0 ) {
/**/    return cont([]);
    }
    let [head, ...tail] = arr;
/**/return getSublistsWithFixedSize(tail, size - 1, function (sublists0) {
/**/    return getSublistsWithFixedSize(tail, size, function (sublists1) {
            let sublists2 = sublists0.map(x => {
                let y = x.slice();
                y.unshift(head);
                return y;
            });
/**/        return cont(sublists1.concat(sublists2));
        });
    });
}

console.log(getSublistsWithFixedSize([1,2,3,4], 2))
// [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]
```

You can think of the continuation almost like we invent our own `return` mechanism; only it's a function here, not a special syntax.

This is perhaps more apparent if we specify our own continuation at the call site

```
getSublistsWithFixedSize([1,2,3,4], 2, console.log)
// [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]
```

Or even

```
getSublistsWithFixedSize([1,2,3,4], 2, sublists => sublists.length)
// 6
```

---

The pattern might be easier to see with a simpler function. Consider the famous `fib`

```
const fib = n =>
  n < 2
    ? n
    : fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)

console.log (fib (10))
// 55
```

Below we convert it to continuation-passing style

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const fib = (n, _return = identity) =>
  n < 2
    ? _return (n)
    : fib (n - 1, x =>
        fib (n - 2, y =>
          _return (x + y)))

fib (10, console.log)
// 55

console.log (fib (10))
// 55
```

---

I want to remark that the use of `.slice` and `.unshift` is unnecessary for this particular problem. I'll give you an opportunity to come up with some other solutions before sharing an alternative.

---

Edit

You did a good job rewriting your program, but as you identified, there are still areas which it can be improved. One area I think you're struggling the most is by use of array mutation operations like `arr[0] = x` or `arr.push(x)`, `arr.pop()`, and `arr.unshift(x)`. Of course you can use these operations to arrive at the intended result, but in a functional program, we think about things in a different way. Instead of destroying an old value by overwriting it, we only *read* values and construct *new* ones.

We'll also avoid high level operations like `Array.fill` or `uniq` (unsure which implementation you chose) as we can build the result naturally using recursion.

The inductive reasoning for your recursive function is perfect, so we don't need to adjust that

1. if the `size` is zero, return the empty result `[[]]`
2. if the input array is empty, return an empty set, `[]`
3. otherwise the `size` is at least one and we have at least one element `x` - get the sublists of one size smaller `r1`, get the sublists of the same size `r2`, return the combined result of `r1` and `r2` prepending `x` to each result in `r1`

We can encode this in a straightforward way. Notice the similarity in structure compared to your original program.

```
const sublists = (size, [ x = None, ...rest ], _return = identity) =>
  size === 0
    ? _return ([[]])

  : x === None
    ? _return ([])

  : sublists              // get sublists of 1 size smaller, r1
      ( size - 1
      , rest
      , r1 =>
          sublists        // get sublists of same size, r2
            ( size
            , rest
            , r2 =>
                _return   // return the combined result
                  ( concat
                      ( r1 .map (r => prepend (x, r)) // prepend x to each r1
                      , r2
                      )
                  )
            )
      )
```

We call it with a `size` and an input array

```
console.log (sublists (2, [1,2,3,4,5]))
// [ [ 1, 2 ]
// , [ 1, 3 ]
// , [ 1, 4 ]
// , [ 1, 5 ]
// , [ 2, 3 ]
// , [ 2, 4 ]
// , [ 2, 5 ]
// , [ 3, 4 ]
// , [ 3, 5 ]
// , [ 4, 5 ]
// ]
```

Lastly, we provide the dependencies `identity`, `None`, `concat`, and `prepend` - Below `concat` is an example of providing a functional interface to an object's method. This is one of the many techniques used to increase reuse of functions in your programs and help readability at the same time

```
const identity = x =>
  x 

const None =
  {}

const concat = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .concat (ys)

const prepend = (value, arr) =>
  concat ([ value ], arr)
```

You can run the full program in your browser below

```js
const identity = x =>
  x 
  
const None =
  {}

const concat = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .concat (ys)

const prepend = (value, arr) =>
  concat ([ value ], arr)

const sublists = (size, [ x = None, ...rest ], _return = identity) =>
  size === 0
    ? _return ([[]])
  
  : x === None
    ? _return ([])

  : sublists             // get sublists of 1 size smaller, r1
      ( size - 1
      , rest
      , r1 =>
          sublists       // get sublists of same size, r2
            ( size
            , rest
            , r2 =>
                _return   // return the combined result
                  ( concat
                      ( r1 .map (r => prepend (x, r)) // prepend x to each r1
                      , r2
                      )
                  )
            )
      )

console.log (sublists (3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
// [ [ 1, 2, 3 ]
// , [ 1, 2, 4 ]
// , [ 1, 2, 5 ]
// , [ 1, 2, 6 ]
// , [ 1, 2, 7 ]
// , [ 1, 3, 4 ]
// , [ 1, 3, 5 ]
// , [ 1, 3, 6 ]
// , [ 1, 3, 7 ]
// , [ 1, 4, 5 ]
// , [ 1, 4, 6 ]
// , [ 1, 4, 7 ]
// , [ 1, 5, 6 ]
// , [ 1, 5, 7 ]
// , [ 1, 6, 7 ]
// , [ 2, 3, 4 ]
// , [ 2, 3, 5 ]
// , [ 2, 3, 6 ]
// , [ 2, 3, 7 ]
// , [ 2, 4, 5 ]
// , [ 2, 4, 6 ]
// , [ 2, 4, 7 ]
// , [ 2, 5, 6 ]
// , [ 2, 5, 7 ]
// , [ 2, 6, 7 ]
// , [ 3, 4, 5 ]
// , [ 3, 4, 6 ]
// , [ 3, 4, 7 ]
// , [ 3, 5, 6 ]
// , [ 3, 5, 7 ]
// , [ 3, 6, 7 ]
// , [ 4, 5, 6 ]
// , [ 4, 5, 7 ]
// , [ 4, 6, 7 ]
// , [ 5, 6, 7 ]
// ]
```

Comment: Wow, this style is indeed very "functional". Just leant it, thanks.

Comment: @user1285245 very nice job on reworking your program. I provided an update with a few added remarks. If you found this helpful, I encourage you to read some of my other [javascript answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20%5bjavascript%5d); they are written using similar styles and techniques :D