# How to refactor a binary recursion to make it compatible with trampoline function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

I've written a quick sort function like this:

```
const quickSort = list => {
  if (list.length === 0) return list
  const [pivot, ...rest] = list
  const smaller = []
  const bigger = []
  for (x of rest) {
    x < pivot ? smaller.push(x) : bigger.push(x)
  }

  return [...quickSort(smaller), pivot, ...quickSort(bigger)]
}
```

I want to pass this function to a trampoline function to make it more efficient. However, to make a recursion function compatible with trampoline, I have to return a function that calls the outer function. As is shown below:

```
const trampoline = fn => (...args) => {
  let result = fn(...args)
  while (typeof result === "function") {
    result = result()
  }
  return result
}

const sumBelowRec = (number, sum = 0) => (
  number === 0
    ? sum
    : () => sumBelowRec(number - 1, sum + number)
)

const sumBelow = trampoline(sumBelowRec)
sumBelow(100000)
// returns 5000050000
```

How can I transform my `quickSort` function to make it leverage the `trampoline` function?

Comment: I like this q because it is a really good teaching example with nice modern js and functional-programming (upvote)

Comment: A trampoline does not increase efficiency – in fact, it's likely to have a lower performance profile in almost all cases. The only reason you use a trampoline is so that you can prevent a recursive program from blowing the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To utilize a trampoline, your recursive function must be [*tail recursive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Your `quickSort` function is **not** tail recursive because recursive calls to `quickSort` do not appear in tail position, ie

```
return [...quickSort(smaller), pivot, ...quickSort(bigger)]
```

Maybe it's hard to see in your program, but the tail call in your program is an array concat operation. If you were to write it without using ES6 syntaxes, we could see this more readily

```
const a = quickSort(smaller)
const b = quickSort(bigger)
const res1 = a.concat(pivot)
const res2 = res1.concat(b) // <-- last operation is a concat
return res2
```

In order to make `quickSort` tail recursive, we can express our program using [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). Transforming our program is simple: we do this by adding a parameter to our function and using it to specify how the computation should continue. The default continuation is the `identity` function which simply passes its input to output – changes in **bold**

```
const identity = x =>
  x

const quickSort = (list, cont = identity) => {
  if (list.length === 0)
    return cont(list)

  const [pivot, ...rest] = list
  const smaller = []
  const bigger = []
  for (const x of rest) { // don't forget const keyword for x here
    x < pivot ? smaller.push(x) : bigger.push(x)
  }

  return quickSort (smaller, a =>
           quickSort (bigger, b =>
             cont ([...a, pivot, ...b])))
}
```

Now we can see that `quickSort` always appears in tail position. However, if we call our function with a large input, direct recursion will cause many call frames to accumulate and eventually overflow the stack. To prevent this from happening, we `bounce` each tail call on a trampoline

```
const quickSort = (list, cont) => {
  if (list.length === 0)
    return bounce (cont, list);

  const [pivot, ...rest] = list
  const smaller = []
  const bigger = []
  for (const x of rest) {
    x < pivot ? smaller.push(x) : bigger.push(x)
  }

  return bounce (quickSort, smaller, a =>
           bounce (quickSort, larger, b =>
             bounce (cont, [...a, pivot, ...b])))
}
```

Now we need a `trampoline`

```
const bounce = (f, ...args) =>
  ({ tag: bounce, f, args })

const trampoline = t =>
{ while (t && t.tag === bounce)
    t = t.f (...t.args)
  return t
}
```

Sure enough it works

```
console.log (trampoline (quickSort ([ 6, 3, 4, 8, 1, 6, 2, 9, 5, 0, 7 ])))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

We verify that it works with big data. A million numbers between zero and one million...

```
const rand = () =>
  Math.random () * 1e6 >> 0

const big = 
  Array.from (Array (1e6), rand)

console.time ('1 million numbers')
console.log (trampoline (quickSort (big)))
console.timeEnd ('1 million numbers')
// [ 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, ... 999990 more items ]
// 1 million numbers: 2213 ms
```

---

In another question [I answered recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776749/633183), I show the conversion of two other common functions into continuation-passing style.

Stack-safe recursion is something I've covered broadly, with [almost 30 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+stack-safe) on the topic

Answer (score -1):

I can not see how trampoline would make your `quickSort` more efficient. The least thing you will add is the hard string based check if you are in the state of returning, having a value, or in the state of further dividing the result, having a function. This will add quite a bit to the computation time.

What you can do is make it more generic. In general I would say trampoline is a good way to explain what recursion is about, but never good in terms of efficiency compared to the direct function call.

Further, **to leverage trampoline, you must create a function that either returns a function or a value**. But you need s.th. that **can return a divide** (there are **two recursive sub-calls** at `quickSort`). That is way you need to reuse trampoline (kind of recursion inside your recursion, 2nd level recursion you might want to call it).

```js
const qs = (list) => {
  if (list.length === 0)
    return list;
  const [pivot, ...rest] = list;
  const smaller = [];
  const bigger = [];
  for (let x of rest) {
    x < pivot ? smaller.push(x) : bigger.push(x);
  }
  return [...trampoline(qs)(smaller), pivot, ...trampoline(qs)(bigger)];
};
const trampoline = fn => (...args) => {
  let result = fn(...args);
  while (typeof result === "function") {
    result = result();
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(trampoline(qs)([1, 6, 2, 4]));
console.log(trampoline(qs)([4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 2]));
```

I checked with Chromium and this code is actually really working and even sorting.

Did I already mention: this can not be faster then the original direct recursive calls. This will stack up a lot of function objects.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the performance of both trampoline(qs) and the original quickSort, turns out that the latter is slightly faster. I also found that the imperative version of quick sort is far more performant than my recursion one. So if performance is a concern, should we avoid using recursion?

Comment: As far as I remember, a so called "end-recursion" is always transformable into an iteration. And yes, prefer iteration, if you can. There might be a huge difference between iteration and recursion in performance. The most famous example is fib(x). Go further and check O-notation!

Comment: This is not valid use of a trampoline. In your program, `trampoline` calls `qs` which calls `trampoline` which calls `qs`... This is [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) and you will still experience a stack overflow if the input data is large enough

Comment: @user633183 answer already mentioning the recursion problem and also the stack problem (but thanks for precise english terms, my study days are long ago)

Comment: @user633183 After some more reading: I get what you are pointing at. It is true my answer is fixing it purely from the syntactic point of view. It is NOT optimizing it to tail recursion (i remember term "Endrekursion" in German) and then transforming it into an iteration, removing the stack issue.

Comment: @Martin but *"fixing it"* is misleading because the very purpose of a trampoline is to avoid a stack overflow. `trampoline` as you've used it here can still blow the stack and so we've added complexity and performance cost for no gain. But yes, it compiles and runs :D